# Logging application start and end in struts2 application using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat7

I would like to ask something about log4j usage in my Struts2 application. I'm using log4j in my struts2 application. here is my `log4j.xml`.

```
 <appender name="APPLICATION" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${appRootPath}/application_"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c %m%n"/>
    </layout>
 </appender>

 <appender name="JUNIT" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <param name="file" value="application.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
           <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c %m%n"/>
      </layout>
 </appender>

 <logger name="co.jkk.tds">
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="JUNIT"/>
       <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
 </logger>
```

I used ServletContextListener to configure this log4j xml to my application.This is my listener class,

```
     public class Log4jInit implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        CommonUtil.methodInfoLog(this.getClass(), "contextDestroyed",
                        MethodAction.Start);
        CommonUtil.methodInfoLog(this.getClass(), "contextDestroyed",
                        MethodAction.Finish);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
        ServletContext ctx = e.getServletContext();
        System.setProperty("appRootPath", ctx.getRealPath("/logs"));
        String prefix = ctx.getRealPath("/");
        String file = "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "classes" + File.separator
                        + "log4j.xml";
        DOMConfigurator.configure(prefix + file);

    }
}
```

My question is How can I add application start and end log messages in my Struts2 application?I'm using Tomcat7 and Struts2.

Answer (score 0):

It has got nothing to do with struts2. The way you are initializing log4j in context listener looks right. Make sure you have configured `web.xml` to invoke your context listener by addling `<listener>` element to web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.package.Log4jInit</listener-class> <!-- Use fully qualified name of y our Log4jInit class. -->
</listener>
```

After that you can use log4j loggers to log the events like context begin and end.

Please note - I have not analyzed your log4j appenders and logger configuration.